# How to upgrade our controls from version 1.6.1 to 1.8.1

Tags: ember.js

I just referenced version 1.8.1 and am immediately greeted by the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Resolved the view "Komodo.Controls.Button" on the
>   global context. Pass a view name to be looked up on the container
>   instead, such as {{view "select"}}.
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_global-lookup-of-views-since-1-81

For our framework we have created numerous controls and they are used like so:

```
{{view Komodo.Controls.TextField ... }} 
{{view Komodo.Controls.Select ... }} 
{{view Komodo.Controls.CoreTextLabel ... }} 
etc.
```

What will we need to do w.r.t. our controls to use them in v1.8.1? Is there some quick fix, or would we need to create, say, components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @NicholasJohn16 mentions is true if the view was `App.TextfieldView`, however i assume that `Komodo.Controls` comes from  multiple namespaces  i.e. `Komodo` and `Komodo.Controls`, as in a separate library.

In this case the following three approaches will work,

**1.** Write a helper for each control. (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_custom-view-helpers)

example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wayuwubemi/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("komodo-textfield", Komodo.Controls.TextField);
```

**hbs**

```
....
{{komodo-textfield}}
....
```

---

**2.** Create properties pointing to these controls in your view or controller.

example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rogufarute/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  komodoTField:Komodo.Controls.TextField
});
```

**hbs**

```
....
{{view view.komodoTField}}
....
```

---

**3.** Register the controls in the container as mentioned in *dependency injection and service lookup* (http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_dependency-injection-with-code-register-inject-code)

example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jematokivu/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.register('view:komodoTField', Komodo.Controls.TextField);
```

**hbs**

```
....
{{view "komodoTField"}}
....
```

---

The approaches that i followed while migrating an application from 1.5.1 to 1.8.1 were 1 and 2.

Also i think it is best to use components in these cases.

Comment: Excellent response, thanks!  This will have quite a significant impact on our code base (~6000 usages in ~250 hbs files).  Would there be any issues w.r.t. bindings and the like for any of the options or would the controls continue to work as before?

Comment: Thanks @EbenRoux i'm glad you found it useful. Everything should work as before, i didn't actually have to make any other changes regarding views. Although i did have issues with few components in block form that were calling their own properties within the body of the block. For example when using notation of the form `{{#my-comp prop1=theProp1}}  {{view.prop1}}  {{/my-comp}}`, it had to change to `{{#my-comp prop1=theProp1 viewName="thisInstanceOfMyComp"}} {{view.thisInstanceOfMyComp.prop1}} {{/my-comp}}`, as `view` was referring to the rendering view containing the component.

Comment: Was wondering if you know. If I were to create a component in v1.6.1 would it be 100% compatible with v1.8.1 or would there, yet again, be changes?

Comment: @EbenRoux based on  release notes and experience of the migration from v1.5.1 to v1.8.1 all the components continue to work as before so they should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer pass in view instances to the view helper.  Instead, just the view name so something like this:

```
{{view "textfield"}}
```

Where the view is defined as App.TextfieldView. Should be as easy as updating your templates to match the new syntax.

Comment: I did spot this :) --- but our controls are not on the App namespace.